# SSIS : how to perform query with Exists

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database

I would like to perform a query with an EXIST clause using SSIS.

Inputs are an Excel file sheet and a Azure SQL table.

The objective is to get the rows in the table that meet certain condition in the excel file.

What is the best way of solving this in SSIS?

The solution that comes to my mind is to insert the excel file rows in a temp Azure SQL table and then perform an T-SQL query but I was wondering whether there was an alternative that does not imply bulk inserting records in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options:

1. Import all data and use a conditional split to get out unwanted records.

   a. Test each row element for what you want to exclude and map to nothing

   b. What is left are your good records
2. Use an OleDb connection (to Excel Source) and write a SQL statement on your source to get the records that you want. Assumes all where clauses are in the source.

Now that I think about it more. I am guessing here, but I think you might be wanting to compare a value to see if it exists in the DB already.

For this case...
Import all data and use a lookup. Make sure you choose your no match option. You usually use this approach to know whether your row is an insert or an update. Caching choices are important here, but that is another topic.

Comment: thanks, I think the the lookup approach is the one that would work here. 2) is not feasible because of what you mention regarding the clauses in the source